# Scrape ASP.NET site with dynamic combo dropdown box with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select

I am trying to scrape [this](http://www.etcfinance.com.hk/online_appraise.aspx) page written in ASP.NET with 7 dynamic combo drop down box using PhantomJS v1.9.8.

My JS is as follow:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('User agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';
page.open('http://www.etcfinance.com.hk/online_appraise.aspx', function(status) {
    page.injectJs("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
          $("#ddlArea").val('香港');
          __doPostBack('ddlArea', '');
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Zone: ' + $('#ddlZone').val());
          }, 1000);
        });
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

The output hangs at :

```
User agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34
```

but does not proceed afterwards. How can I select all those combo dropdown boxes' with desired values?

The concerned part of HTML is as follow:

```
<table xwidth="100%" width="460" bgcolor="#E0F3FF" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="content">
<tbody><tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="insidecontent"> 
  <td style="Padding-Left:20px;Padding-Right:20px;"> 
    <div align="left"> 區域 : </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"> 
  <select name="ddlArea" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlArea\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlArea" class="textbox" style="width:29em">
        <option selected="selected" value="">請選擇區域</option>
        <option value="香港">香港</option>
        <option value="九龍">九龍</option>
        <option value="新界/離島">新界/離島</option>

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="insidecontent"> 
  <td style="Padding-Left:20px;Padding-Right:20px;"> 
    <div align="left"> 分區 : </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"> 
    <select name="ddlZone" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlZone\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlZone" class="textbox" style="width:29em">

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="insidecontent"> 
  <td style="Padding-Left:20px;Padding-Right:20px;"> 
    <div align="left"> 屋苑名稱 : </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"> 
    <select name="ddlestate" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlestate\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlestate" class="textbox" style="width:29em">

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="insidecontent"> 
  <td style="Padding-Left:20px;Padding-Right:20px;"> 
    <div align="left"> 座數/座名 : </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"> 
    <select name="ddlblock" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlblock\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlblock" class="textbox" style="width:29em">

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="insidecontent"> 
  <td style="Padding-Left:20px;Padding-Right:20px;"> 
    <div align="left"> 層數 : </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"> 
    <select name="ddlfloor" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlfloor\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlfloor" class="textbox" style="width:29em">

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="insidecontent"> 
  <td style="Padding-Left:20px;Padding-Right:20px;"> 
    <div align="left" id="div1"> 室 : </div>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"> 
    <div id="div2"> 
    <select name="ddlflat" id="ddlflat" class="textbox" style="width:29em">
    </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

*Note: I know the HTML above is full of errors.*

Also, reason that I use `page.injectJS` instead of `page.includeJS` is that the latter function causes the following error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://parse.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.injectJs` doesn't have a callback and can only inject local files. Nothing you wanted executed, is actually executed. You need to use `page.includeJs` to include remote scripts.

So, you can either download put jQuery in the local directory and use `page.injectJs` (simplest solution), or try to make it work with the remote script and `page.includeJs`. This would include running with commandline options like `--web-security=false` and `--local-to-remote-url-access=true`.

Btw, jquery-latest.js is fixed to 1.11.1 for all eternety. If you want newer jQuery, use an actual version number.

There is another problem with your script which you will experience after getting it to work. You `exit` too early. `setTimeout` breaks off the blocking execution flow and `page.evaluate` immediately finishes. The `exit` is called before the `setTimeout` callback is called. Workaround:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    $("#ddlArea").val('香港');
    __doPostBack('ddlArea', '');
});
setTimeout(function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log('Zone: ' + $('#ddlZone').val());
    });
    phantom.exit();
}, 1000);
```

This is better but you will still won't see anything on the console, because you also need to register to the [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) event.

Chained version:

```
var selects = [
    ['ddlArea', '香港'], 
    ['ddlZone', '...'], 
    ...
];

selects.forEach(function(sel, i){
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.evaluate(function(sel) {
            $("#"+sel[0]).val(sel[1]);
            __doPostBack(sel[0], '');
        }, sel);
    }, i * 1000);
});
setTimeout(function() {
    phantom.exit();
}, 1000 * selects.length);
```

A better version would be to use actual clicks and use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait until the next select is populated in conjunction with [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to a correct direction. You mentioned I have to use `.onConsoleMessage()` but why the User Agent line can be shown in console without using the above function ?

Comment: PhantomJS has two environments. `page.evaluate` is the sandboxed page context. You should read the documentation: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html the casper documentation is also quite good: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate (I would suggest to use CasperJS, because it is much easier to write navigation scripts that way)

Comment: How to work out this combo drop down box scenario in casperjs ?

Comment: It's not easier than in PhantomJS. It's only easier when you have to navigate much.

Comment: I just confuse with the multiple `__doPostBack()`. How can I do it in PhantomJS / CasperJS ? It didn't mention in their docs.

Comment: I added a simple suggestion, but there are many many ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, you're helping a lot. I'll figure out the rest .